# C Sockets: Comparison between pointer and integer terminal error

Tags: c, sockets, if-statement, terminal

Here is a simple socket. No matter in which file `if` statement is declared,

```
int main()
{

   int sock, bytes_recieved;//, number;  
   char send_data[1024],recv_data[1024];

   host = gethostbyname("127.0.0.1");

   server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;     
   server_addr.sin_port = htons(1237);   

   while(1)
   { 
      bytes_recieved = recv(sock,recv_data,1024,0);
      recv_data[bytes_recieved] = '\0';

      if (recv_data[0] == "q" || recv_data[0] == "Q")
      {
          printf("Why do you want to close socket dude?\n");
          close(sock);
        break;
      }

   }  
   close(sock);         
   return 0;

}
```

after running both in client and server are coming with the error below in teminal

`client.c:49:26: warning: comparison between pointer and integer
         if (recv_data[0] == "q" || recv_data[0] == "Q")
                          ^`

Comment: When you  put `"q"` it thinks q is a string since its in double quotes try `if (recv_data[0] == 'q' || recv_data[0] == 'Q')`

Comment: recv_data[0] is a char, "q" is a char[2]. What do you want to do exactly?

Comment: thank you so much JackWilliams. I began using with sockets and this is first time I am using it. It is quite crazy when one is passes from JavaScript to C :)

Comment: @developer Glad i could help. You clearly didnt understand the warning though so as an explanation. A character in C is represented as an integer data type (technically the letter q is int value 113) and a string in C is really a pointer to the first character in the string. Which is why we have the error comparison between pointer (the string q) and integer (the character `recv_data[0]`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you should check that `bytes_received` is not negative before the line

```
recv_data[bytes_recieved] = '\0';
```

because not only does this indicate an error, but prevents you from writing to a negative index which is undefined behaviour.

Secondly, the type of `recv_data[0]` is `char` while `"q"` is a string literal and of type `char*` so

```
if (recv_data[0] == "q" || recv_data[0] == "Q")
```

is not a valid comparison (as the compiler indicates).

Replace the above line line with

```
if (recv_data[0] == 'q' || recv_data[0] == 'Q')
```

to check for specific characters `q` and `Q` at element zero in your receive buffer.

Comment: Also note that 'recv_data[bytes_recieved] = '\0';' will write out-of-bounds if  all 1024 bytes are received.

Answer (score -1):

You can't compare a character to a string.